# HTML Code Issue‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎‏‎ ‎

Tags: html

I have the following HTML code on my website for a share button, but when it's clicked a white outline seems to appear. Can someone help me remove this as I don't know what is causing it.

Thanks.

```
    <style>
        a {
            color: #000000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:hover {
            color: #000000;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        body {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: black;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            scroll-behavior: none;
        }

        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .zoomA {
            width: 60px;
            height: auto;
            /* ease | ease-in | ease-out | linear */
            transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s;
        }

        img {
            border: 0;
        }

        .zoomA:hover {
            transform: scale(1.4);
        }

        body {
            font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, San Francisco, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Ubuntu, Roboto, Noto, Segoe UI, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }

        svg {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            margin-right: 7px;
        }

        button,
        .button {
            display: inline-flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: auto;
            padding-top: 8px;
            padding-bottom: 8px;
            color: #b7b7b7;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 500;
            line-height: 1.1;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            text-decoration: none;
            white-space: nowrap;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #00cc69;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: #000;
        }

        button:hover,
        .button:hover {
            border-color: #00cc69;
            background: #000;
            color: #b7b7b7;
            outline-color: #000;
            text-decoration-color:#000;
        }

        button:active,
        .button:active {
            border-color: #00cc69;
            background: #000;
            color: #b7b7b7;
            outline-color: initial #000;
            text-decoration-color:#000;
            background-image: none;
        }

        .share-button,
        .copy-link {
            padding-left: 30px;
            padding-right: 30px;
        }

        .share-button,
        .share-dialog {
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
    <button class="share-button" type="button" title="Share">
        <svg>

            <use href="#share-icon"></use>

        </svg>
        <span>Share</span>
    </button>
    <svg class="hidden">
        <defs>
            <symbol id="share-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2"
                stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-share">
                <path d="M4 12v8a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-8"></path>
                <polyline points="16 6 12 2 8 6"></polyline>
                <line x1="12" y1="2" x2="12" y2="15"></line>
            </symbol>
        </defs>
    </svg>
    <script id="rendered-js">
        const shareButton = document.querySelector('.share-button');
        const shareDialog = document.querySelector('.share-dialog');
        const closeButton = document.querySelector('.close-button');
        shareButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
            if (navigator.share) {
                navigator.share({

                    title: 'example.com',

                    text: 'Check out this website I found.',

                    url: 'https://example.com'
                }).

                    then(() => {

                        console.log('Thanks for sharing!');

                    }).

                    catch(console.error);

            } else {
                shareDialog.classList.add('is-open');
            }
        });
        closeButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
            shareDialog.classList.remove('is-open');
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

Comment: I tried running your code. Didn't see any issue. can you please a screenshot having that white outline issue you mentioned?

Comment: Sure. Here is a video. https://RyderCragie.com/WhiteBox.mp4

Comment: Is my browser causing this?